Influence of wind on an aircraft’s ground speed
I wonder if you can help settle this argument.
An aircraft is flying in circles, with a constant angle of bank, at a constant airspeed of 80kts, at a constant altitude, in a steady 20kt wind from the east.
The argument is about what causes the changes in groundspeed as the aircraft circles.
One side of the argument states that it’s simply the wind component that is causing the changes in groundspeed to be observed in the ground-based frame of reference.
The other side claims that because the groundspeed is accelerating and decelerating, a newtonian force must be the cause. They don’t accept that the wind is the cause, because ‘wind isn’t a force’. They claim that the vectored lift force produced by the wings is causing the changes in groundspeed.
ChatGPT states that the movement of the airmass is the cause, but the ‘force not wind’ side of the argument do not accept that ChatGPT is reliable when it comes to physics problems.
ChatGPT produced a script that accurately predicted the groundspeed and every 10-degree increment by using the airspeed and windspeed values. These results were rejected as ‘over simplistic’ by the ‘force not wind’ side.
So is it just the wind component or is it more complicated?

You are both right.
The airplane doesn't know the ground is there. It flies in circles at constant speed through the air. Anything that moves in a circle is accelerating toward the center of the circle. There must be a force that does the accelerating. This force comes from air blowing over the wings and being deflected.
If the air is still, the track over the ground is a circle. The speed is constant. Speed is a number. But the velocity keeps changing. Velocity is a vector, speed and direction. The velocity is east on one side of the circle and west on the other.
If the air is moving east at a constant speed, the circles drift east. The total velocity is the sum of the drift and circular velocities. The track over the ground is loops that drift east. So adding the wind component to circles produces a faster speed when traveling east than west.
Because the air's drift velocity is constant, no force is required to keep it drifting. There is no additional force on the airplane. The force on the airplane is toward the center of the drifting mass of air the plane flies through.
These forces change the velocity in a similar way whether or not the air is still. They reverse the direction of the plane on opposite sides of the circle. If the air is moving, the result is a moving circle, where the speed on the side moving east is bigger than the side moving west.
Wind is not a force. It is moving air. Wind causes a force on objects.

You got lucky with chatGPT if the script produced correct results. Sometimes you get a good answer. Sometimes you get nonsense.

Thanks so much. To clarify, is it just the wind component causing the changes in groundspeed as the airmass moves?

I'll start by addressing the ChatGPT argument.  ChatGPT is notoriously for making good looking arguments that lack content (or are even wrong).   "Wind isn’t a force" is true, but only on a technicality.  Wind is the motion of air molecules.  That in and of itself is not a force.  However, wind can apply a force to an object if that object's velocity is different from the air's velocity.  In this case, the airplane's wings are moving at a different velocity, so the wind does apply a force to the aircraft.
The next tricky piece is causality.  This is a notoriously tricky thing which I have seen countless physics students struggle with.  From one side of the argument you say, "...it's simply the wind component that is causing the changes in groundspeed to be observed in the ground-based frame of reference."  This is actually a really tricky part of physics, because the laws of physics are actually non-causal (in the ontological sense*).  They simply state what happens, not why it happens.  This is tricky because us humans are really good at divining causality.  To create a mathematical example, consider $1+2+2$:
I say $1+2+2=5$ because $2+2=4$ and $1+(2+2)=1+4=5$.
You say $1+2+2=5$ because $1+2=3$ and $1+2+2=(1+2)+2 = 3+2=5$.
Who is right?  The real answer is that we both applied causality with "because," when the equation itself was agnostic to why it was true.  It was simply true.
In the ground-frame-only approach, the wind must be applying a time-varying force on the aircraft which is non-zero on average.  Thus the plane drifts over time.  In the air-frame approach, the wind is applying a force to the aircraft with a constant magnitude but varying direction (which is what circular motion looks like).  It has an average of 0 in the air's frame of reference (note that force can and do change when changing frames of reference.  Arguably that's why we do it).  The aircraft is simply doing a circle, which is then transformed into ground-speed.
Neither one causes the effect in physics.  However, in the minds of human beings thinking about the problem, we almost always think about this problem in the air's reference frame or the aircraft's reference frame.  We do this because the mathematics is simplest in this form.  It is far easier to think about a propeller operating in a fixed air frame or a fixed propeller operating in the aircraft's frame (such that the air is moving backwards across the propeller at exactly the aircraft's airspeed) than it is to try to think of the complex interaction between the propeller and a moving air volume, especially as the aircraft turns.
It is common to say that an effect causes something when that effect is in its simplest form.  That's not physics, its just human nature.  The physics doesn't depend on causality.  In fact, that is one of the shining reasons we love physics so much.  If we concoct an experiment, and go about reasoning about it differently, we come to the same conclusion.  In this case, both parties will agree on the exact same path for the aircraft.  The numbers will be different because we're thinking about it differently, but both of us will agree that the plane took the exact path we predicted.  This independence from the human mind reasoning about it is what makes physics so strong.
*. Causality in the ontological sense is the idea that one thing causes another to happen.  I put this footnote here because we also define "causal" systems mathematically and physics does indeed always have this mathematical concept of causality.  There are only so many words in the English language, and we love to double-dip on the best of them!

Thanks Cort. One thing, it’s the relative wind that moves the wing, not the movement of the airmass (wind). Is it true to say that the changes in groundspeed speed are the result of the movement of the airmass?
